# Kernel Module Make file problem

Tags: makefile, kernel-module

This is the first time I am trying to build kernal module. Following is make file. On running make command. I get the error

/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

make: *** [all] Error 2

```
obj-m =mod.o
obj-m +=depmod.o

obj-m +=mod1.o
obj-m +=mod2.o
obj-m +=mod3.o


KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean: 
        rm -rf $(wildcard *.o *.ko *.mod.* .c* .t* test Module.symvers *.order *.markers)
```

Comment: Try to echo "$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules" expression to check how it's expanded. Add after KDIR= : $(warning Test = $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD))

Comment: Yes I have problem in PWD in the directory name "(" is present , after renaming my directory problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel release (given by `uname -r`) can have parentheses in it, and in this case I'll bet it does. This means that a) it doesn't do well as part of a path, and b) the shell doesn't like receiving it in the middle of a Make command. I suggest you translate the parentheses into, say, underscores:

```
KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r | sed s/[\(\)]/_/g)/build
```

(`uname -r` can also give you forward slashes, which you can deal with the same way if you have to.)

Comment: I can not find any example of parentheses nor slashes, do you have any ? for (my) culture.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should properly quote the arguments, i.e.

`${MAKE} -C "${KDIR}" M="${PWD}" modules`

Also, for `clean:` you should similarly use

`${MAKE} -C "${KDIR}" M="${PWD}" clean`

instead of trying to match all the files generated by Kbuild yourself with some wildcards (that's just not future-proof).